# Moving attribute data to the objects geometry

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have contour lines with the elevations of them in an attribute called 'CONTOUR' however these do not actually elevate the lines when I bring them into AutoCAD.  To do this I want to copy and paste the 'CONTOUR' attribute information and paste it into the 'ELEVATION' attribute as shown in the table.  When I Join the excel sheet to the shapefile it doesn't bring in the elevations though and I am not sure why.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the results I wanted but only through the Query command in AutoCAD.  Tutorial can be found here: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Importing-an-ESRI-shapefile-with-elevation-values-s.html

Answer (score 4):

When exporting the contour lines you also can use the OSgeo4W Shell:

- Navigate to your folder where your shapefile is located
- use this comand:

  ```
  ogr2ogr -f DXF output.dxf input.shp -zfield CONTOUR
  ```
- ignore the warnings you will get
- the zfield argument adds the height information to you dxf file, which is created in the same folder as the input.shp

Comment: I use the command in the OSgeo4W shell as I am navigating to the folder in the QGIS browser?  Not much experience with the shell.

Comment: @Jhunt9  lets say your countour,shp file sits in C:\myfolder\my_otherfolder. So you would navigate to this folder  with `cd C:\myfolder\my_otherfolder`

Comment: My shp file is in my temp folder.  So exactly what do I type into my Shell?        >cd C:\temp      >>ogr2ogr -f DXF output.dxf input.shp -zfield CONTOUR

Comment: @Jhunt9 yeah if your shapefile is named "input" then it should work else it would be something like `cd C:\temp` and then `ogr2ogr -f DXF output.dxf my_file_name.shp -zfield CONTOUR` the CONTOUR is name of the attribute field where the height information is stored#

Comment: My file name is 'CCC' it gives me a syntax because of the DXF.  What i typed into the shell from start to finish is : >python   (Next Line) cd C:\temp  (Next Line) ogr2ogr -f DXF output.dxf CCC.shp -zfield CONTOUR

Comment: I get an invalid syntax error.  File "<stdin>:, line 1   cd C:\temp.  I edited my post to show it.

Comment: I got it to work but now the DXF file doesnt have the correct features.  It doesn't include the elevations.

Comment: @Jhunt9 - Do not type `python`, restart the OSGeo4W shell then type the command in.

Comment: @Joseph edited my post again to show what happened now.

Comment: @Jhunt9 very strange. I don't see where it gets lost. I 've tested this approach several times for a colleague and it worked just fine with the very same command

Comment: @LaughU I feel it is because I imported the shapefile from AutoCAD and it got rid of all the Object Data fields.  Not sure how to accomplish that though.